# How to hide title/message frame in a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

When using a `UIAlertController`, if I want to present a `UIActionSheet` with an empty title and an empty message, the frame for the expected placement of the title and/or message remains.

How do I change this so that I only present an `ActionSheet` that reads:


Settings

Sign out

Cancel
?

Thanks!

[image: UIAlertController example]

Answer (score 145, accepted):

When I create a UIAlertController with this code I don't have the title spacing.

```
[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                    message:nil
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
```

Are you passing in nil for the title and message or empty strings?

Comment: That was fairly simple. And that answered my question. Thanks

Comment: Helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had an issue with code I took over - it was using an empty string "" instead of nil. Watch out for that!

Answer (score 18):

**Update Swift 4:**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
```

Just need to pass `nil` to `title` and `message` params.

Comment: This is NO longer valid in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change in run time depending on a certain case just write:

`actionController.title = nil`
`actionController.message = nil`

Answer (score 1):

In swift 2.2, you can use code below and I have also changed the color of signout action button

```
        let actionSheet: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let settingsActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Settings Tapped")
    }

    reportActionSheet.addAction(settingsActionButton)

    let signOutActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Signout", style: .Default)
    { action -> Void in
        //Clear All Method
        print("Signout Tapped")

    }

    signOutActionButton.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKey: "titleTextColor")

    actionSheet.addAction(signOutActionButton)

    let cancelActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        print("Cancel Tapped")
    }

    reportActionSheet.addAction(cancelActionButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove Alert controller top area space. Add Alert controller height

```
let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
alert.view.addConstraint(height);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQqj0.png)

Answer (score -1):

UIAlertController *controller=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];//style check

```
UIAlertAction *first = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Login with Facebook" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
{
   //write to perform action

}];


[controller addAction: first];



UIAlertAction *second = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Guest User" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
```

{
       //write to perform action

```
}];

[controller addAction:second];


UIAlertAction *third=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Registered User" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)


{
    //write to perform action

}];

[controller addAction:third];

[self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
```